# Hibernate doesn't allow to save entity with id, that has been used

Tags: hibernate, generator

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "telegram_id", nullable = false)
private Long telegram_id;
```

When I'm trying to save entity class with an id that has been used in table, but deleted, it stores with auto-incremented one (such option not selected for id during table configuration). What should I change to make it happen.

Comment: just save an object with id i've already use in table

Comment: just reject hibernate, so make impl based on JDBC